# Does there exist a closed form expression for roots of polynomials of the form $x^n + bx + c$

Tags: polynomials, roots, closed-form, inverse-function

Does there exist a closed form expression for roots of polynomials of the form $$x^n + bx + c$$

Where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. $n$ need not be less than five.

Comment: the answer seems to be "No" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

Comment: For $n=5$ and $b,c\in\Bbb Q$, the answer is ["if and only if there exist $\mu,\nu\in\Bbb Q$ such that $b=\frac{5\mu^4(4\nu+3)}{\nu^2+1}$ and $c=\frac{4\mu^5(2\nu+1)(4\nu+3)}{\nu^2+1} $"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Quintics_in_Bring.E2.80.93Jerrard_form).

Comment: You might also be interested in the [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Bring.E2.80.93Jerrard_normal_form). Some quick facts [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760608/can-we-introduce-new-operations-that-make-quintics-solvable/760610#760610), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399711/how-to-find-all-roots-of-the-quintic-using-the-bring-radical) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464700/how-is-it-shown-that-quintic-equations-can-be-solved-by-radicals-and-ultraradica/464709#464709).